# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+(n-1)n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+(r)n}}\right]$$

How can I convert it to Riemann sum because the higher limit is $(n-1)$ not $n$.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes n-> infinity

Comment: If you split $[0,1]$ in $n$ sub intervals and cosider Left Riemann sum, the sample points are $\frac{r}{n}$, where $r=0,\dots, n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as
$$\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac1{n\sqrt{1+\frac{r}n}}\right)-\frac1{n\sqrt{1+\frac{r}{n}}}=\frac1n\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{r}n}}\right)-\frac1{n\sqrt{1+\frac{r}{n}}}$$
Taking the limit gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{r}n}}\right)-\overbrace{\frac1{n\sqrt{1+\frac{r}{n}}}}^{0}\right)=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x}}=[2\sqrt{1+x}]_0^1=\boxed{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}$$

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, there is no need to do this, since you already have a Left Riemann Sum.

Comment: Yes, but this is the form that the OP would understand it in. Obviously the last term will always tend to zero as each point contributes a smaller amount to the original integral as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n(n-1)}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}}$$

Comment: upper limit is (n-1)

Comment: This is not true. Why all of the upvotes?

Comment: The last term in your summation would be $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1+\frac{n-1}{n}}$. That is not equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n(n-1)}} $. If $n$ is say $4$, then the first thing is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{7}$ and the second thing is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}$.

Comment: The summand is $\frac1{\sqrt{1+k/n}}$ not $\sqrt{1+\frac{k}n}$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks

Comment: Your summands are like $\frac{1}{n}(\text{greater than 1})$ but the original summands are like $\frac{1}{n}(\text{less than 1})$.

Comment: @PeterForeman: Yes, thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{r}{n}}}$$.
The term inside the limit is a Left Riemann sum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ in $[0,1]$